# VMWare - RunScriptInGuest, RunProgramInGuest Java - jar excution problem

Tags: java, vmware, vmware-player

I'm trying to execute a jar inside a virtual machine. I'm very new to VMWare and I've hit a brick wall trying to run a jar inside some vms.

I've tried both of the following with no luck.

vmObject.RunProgramInGuest(@"C:\Simulation.jar", "", true, false, false);

vmObject.RunScriptInGuest(@"C:\Simulation.jar","java", true, false);

I'd be grateful for any advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what interface to the API you're using, but it looks like you've got the first two arguments backwards. Here is the function call for reference (from [here](http://www.vmware.com/products/beta/vmware_server/vix_api/ReferenceGuide/lang/com/functions/RunProgramInGuest.html)):

```
HRESULT
RunProgramInGuest([in] BSTR guestProgramName,
                  [in] BSTR commandLineArgs,
                  [in] LONG options,
                  [in] IVixHandle* propertyList,
                  [in] ICallback* jobDoneCallback,
                  [out,retval] IJob** runJob);
```

For running JAR files, the command line executable is `java`, followed by the JAR to execute. For example:

```
java C:\Simulation.jar
```

Reversing your first two arguments should give you the API equivalent of that command:

```
vmObject.RunProgramInGuest("java", @"C:\Simulation.jar", true, false);
```